# How to get the sorted list from aws s3 bucket in an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, sorting, amazon-s3, boto

I’m trying to get the list of an object from aws s3 bucket using boto. This list is made out of common elements of two different list. I want this list to be sorted by "last_modified" of an object by ascending order, from S3 bucket. Meaning, I want the old object (based on the date) to be first on my list. So, I am trying to prepare  list of an 5 elements like this. I want to take this list and process only those files that belong to this list and eventually delete those files and pickup the next list of 5 elements same way.

Here is the bucket hierarchy:-

```
//ship-my-data/outputs/444556677788.tar.gz
//ship-my-data/outputs/444556677788.tar.gz
//ship-my-data/outputs/345345345353.tar.gz

//ship-my-data/outputs1/ctrlFiles/ 444556677788.ctrl.tar.gz
//ship-my-data/outputs1/ctrlFiles/ 123222333444.ctrl.tar.gz
//ship-my-data/outputs1/ctrlFiles/ 769797977979.ctrl.tar.gz
```

I want to make a list of common elements from both the folder above i.e. from `outputs1` & `ctrlFiles` folder.

Here is my code:

```
bucket = LogShip._aws_connection.get_bucket(aws_bucket_to_download) #Connecting to AWS s3 bucket

bucket_list_ctrl = bucket.list(prefix='outputs/ctrlFiles/', delimiter='/') #get the bucket list for control files.
ctrl_list = sorted(bucket_list_ctrl, key=lambda item1: item1.last_modified) # sort the list by last_modified date.

bucket_list_tar = bucket.list(prefix='outputs/', delimiter='/') #get the list for tar files.
tar_list = sorted(bucket_list_tar, key=lambda item2: item2.last_modified) #suppose to get the bucket list, but throwing an error #AttributeError: 'Prefix' object has no attribute 'last_modified'""

for item_c in ctrl_list:
    ctrlName = str(item_c.name).split("/")[2].replace(".ctrl.tar.gz","") # cotrol file name: 1444447203130120001
    for item_t in bucket_list_tar:
        tarName = str(item_t.name).split("/")[1].replace(".tar.gz","") #tar file name: 1444447203130120001
    #now from above two lists I want to prepare a master list of an common elements which is pick up only 5 elements to proceed further.
    j = 5
    while j <= 5:
        for elem in ctrlName:
            for elem in tarName:
                master_list.append(elem)
                j=j+1
            print master_list
```

Output:

```
['c', 't', 'r', 'l', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c', 't', 'r', 'l', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c', 't', 'r', 'l', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c', 't', 'r', 'l', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c', 't', 'r', 'l', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c', 't', 'r', 'l', 'F']
```

Expected output:

```
[444556677788, 123222333444]
```

Can anyone please help me understand where I'm making mistake?

Comment: You are re-using `elem` within two loops. Why are you doing the "list of 5 elements"? It is looping through strings rather than a list of strings.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do things in groups of five, so this code matches all files at once:

```
import boto
import re

conn = boto.connect_s3('REGION')

bucket = conn.get_bucket('BUCKETNAME')

list = bucket.list()

# Get two lists of files
bucket_list_ctrl = bucket.list(prefix='outputs/ctrlFiles/', delimiter='/')
bucket_list_tar  = bucket.list(prefix='outputs/', delimiter='/')

# Extract filenames and modified date
pattern = re.compile('.*?(\d+).*?')
ctrl_files = [(pattern.match(obj.name).group(1), obj.last_modified) for obj in bucket_list_ctrl]
list_files = [pattern.match(obj.name).group(1) for obj in bucket_list_tar if obj.name.endswith('gz')]

# Find filenames that match both
both = [obj for obj in ctrl_files if obj[0] in list_files]

# Give sorted result
result = [f[0] for f in sorted(both, key=lambda obj: obj[1])]
```

Comment: Hi John, it is alway a pleasure to hear from you. Thank you for your solution. The reason I want to do things in group of 5 is that. These individual files i'm trying to process are more than 1GB in size. I am downloading these files and feeding to another steam. So, more than 5 files of this large may create a space issue and other processing issues at the down stream. That's why i want to process 5 files at each run.

Comment: I tried your above code getting an error...                             `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GitRepos/1015/log_ship_dropbox_run.py", line 137, in <module>
    ctrl_files = [(pattern.match(obj.name).group(1), obj.last_modified) for obj in bucket_list_ctrl]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: May be it is not able to find pattern.. what exactly `pattern = re.compile('.*?(\d+).*?')` is doing?

Comment: It is extracting the numbers, which is the part of the filename you wanted. It might fail if there is a directory created manually, which comes back in the S3 bucket listing but isn't a file. You should be able to code around that.

Comment: Thank you John. Let me try to code around it. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi John, I'm trying to code around it , but getting an error. Yes, there is a directory created manually called "ctrlFiles", may be that's why it is failing. I tried to do following. `pattern = re.compile('.*?(\d+).*?')
            if not re.match(r'.*ctrlFiles', pattern):
            #if not re.match(r'.*\.ctrl\.tar\.gz', item_c.name):
                ctrl_files = [(pattern.match(obj.name).group(1), obj.last_modified) for obj in bucket_list_ctrl]
                list_files = [pattern.match(obj.name).group(1) for obj in bucket_list_tar if obj.name.endswith('gz')]`  But getting an error!

Comment: Here is the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GitRepos/1015/test.py", line 88, in <module>
    if not re.match(r'.*ctrlFiles', pattern):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 141, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: can you please help bypass the directory "ctrlFiles"?

Comment: Can you please help? i'm new to this. Thank you!